# Distinguish between web and mobile request in RESTful API, Laravel application

Tags: rest, laravel-5.3, restful-architecture

I am developing an application in `Laravel 5.3` and I am implementing RESTful API(s) for it, and I am trying to avoid redundant codes in the server-side as mush as possible for example I need both mobile application and web application send requests to the same url(s)

for example for updating a category

```
public function update($categoryId)
{
    //some code here   

}
```

both mobile application and web application would send requests to the above function for updating a category, in `CategoryController`

**QUESTION**: I need to find a standard way  the different type of requests, for example the web request should be redirected to a new page but in case of mobile request only a `JSON response` should be sent back to mobile application. what is the standard and right way to distinguish between these requests in the `Controller` to understand which requesrt is sent from which device?

Comment: I would isolate the function inside another class, something like `(new CategoriesRepo)->update($cat_id);` Then you can setup to different routes to handle this, one for desktop version and one for API, do the same call to this class in this function and for each one have a different response on success. on the desktop do `return view('some.view')` and on the mobile to `return response()->json(["success" => true], 200);`

Comment: @AfikDeri thanks for the comment could you please provide this comment in more details as an answer with examples

Answer (score 1):

For a better coding experience and to avoid duplications you can do a Categories Repository and than 2 different controllers to handle desktop/mobile routes.

CategoriesRepository.php

```
class CategoriesRepository{

  public function update($category_id, $data = []){

     $category = Category::findOrFail($category_id);

     return $category->update($data);

  }

  //another category related methods
}
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::group(function(){
    Route::patch("category/{id}", 'CategoriesController@update');
});

//this can also be in the routes/api.php and will get the api prefix automatically
Route::group(["prefix" => "mobile"], function(){
    Route::patch("category/{id}", 'ApiCategoriesController@update');
});
```

CategoriesController.php

```
public function update(Request $request){
  (new CategoriesRepository)->update($request->category_id, $request->only("name", "type"));

  return view("categories.main");
}
```

ApiCategoriesController.php

```
public function update(Request $request){
  (new CategoriesRepository)->update($request->category_id, $request->only("name", "type"));

  return response([
    "success" => true,
    "message" => "The category has been updated successfully"
  ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling your `update` function differently from the web / mobile application, just pass it another parameter, then do a switch or if on that parameter in your controller.